# Conditional type resolving in C# with Unity or MEF

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, unity-container, mef

I'm working on an application architecture and i'm facing a BIG question.
The app is quite simple, it receives a file, the app apply a syntaxe validation,a parsing,... and other stuff.
We can have diffrent type of files (e.g : File1.xx, File2.yy), each File type has a specefic implementation of Syntax validation and parsing.
The main constraint is to have a generic and easily extensible application ( can extend the type of managed files).

That's why i have imagined something like :

An Interface **"IFileProcessor"** in which i have 2 methods (or more) 
**-bool IsSytaxValid(File f)
-String Parse(...)**

In the app i shoud have something like :

```
**// For a current File F1
IFileProcessor fileProcessor;
if (fileProcessor.IsSyntaxtValid(){
fileProcessor.Parse();
}else
 {
  bla bla bla
 }**
```

I want to have a plugin for File1.xx an another from File2.yy(2 dll in which i implement IFileProcessor interface).
The processing implemention, according the current file type, is dynamically loaded.

I have a basic knowledges about Unity and MEF, i know it's my issue is managed by these kind of framworks.

The Question is, which solution is the best to resolve my issue, and how i can do it ?

Thanks in advance for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the file extension to discern between the file types, you can create named registrations for `IFileProcessor` based on the file extension. When resolving the `IFileProcessor`, you use the extension of the file that you want to parse and by that acquire the correct instance.

You can create a named registration like this programmatically:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFileProcessor, TxtFileProcessor>(".txt");
container.RegisterType<IFileProcessor, CsvFileProcessor>(".csv");
```

As you want to use a Plugin model, you can also create the registrations by configuring the Unity container accordingly, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
    </configSections>
    <unity>
        <containers>
            <container>
                <types>
                    <type name=".txt"
                          type="MyNamespace.IFileProcessor, MyAssembly"
                          mapTo="MyPluginNamespace.TxtFileProcessor, MyPluginAssembly"/>
                </types>
            </container>
        </containers>
   </unity>
```

And resolve it like this:

```
var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);
var fileProc = container.Resolve<IFileProcessor>(fileExt.ToLower());
```

Please note that the [GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns the leading "." of the extension, so you either have to remove it or configure your mapping names with a leading ".".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what i expected.
The Xml configuration is perfect for my use case.
Thank you Markus

Comment: @Moon: good to hear that it was useful. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.